# Permission denied heroku error in jar dependency

Tags: java, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a java web app to heroku and I'm getting permission denied error in one of my dependencies which is "aether-api-1.7.jar". I already add a realease command to prevent this error but it kept.

Procfile:

```
release: chmod u+x target/dependency/aether-api-1.7.jar
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -cp target/classes;target/dependency/* Server
```

Heroku logs:

```
2019-11-17T06:10:24.922962+00:00 app[web.1]: See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
2019-11-17T06:10:24.934033+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: target/dependency/aether-api-1.7.jar: Permission denied
2019-11-17T06:10:24.987470+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 126
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `;` in your `Procfile` to `:`. The `;` is causing the rest of the command to be treated as a different command.

The `release` command can't modify your files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it in Procfile:
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar ./build/libs/your-file-0.0.1.jar

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).